# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6725A2B42 и нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

struct matrix {
    int columns;
    int rows;
};

void processingAction() {

}

void manualFillingAction() {
    
}

void deleteAction(int row, int* elements[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        delete[] elements[i];
    delete[] elements;
}

void randomFillingAction(int row, int col, int* elements[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            elements[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 20;
    }
}

void showAction(int row, int col, int* elements[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cout << elements[i][j] << "\t";//ошибка тут 
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void createAction() {
    int choice;
    matrix* array = new matrix();
    cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
    cin >> array->rows;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов: ";
    cin >> array->columns;
    cout << endl;
    int **elements = new int* [array->rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < array->rows; ++i)
        elements[i] = new int[array->columns];
    
    cout << "Выберите способ заполнения матрицы" << endl 
        << "Введите число 1, если хотите заполнить матрицу случайными числами" << endl 
        << "Введите число 2, если хотите заполнить матрицу с клавиатуры" << endl;
    cout << "Ваш выбор: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        randomFillingAction(array->rows, array->columns, elements);
        showAction(array->rows, array->columns, elements);
        deleteAction(array->rows, elements);
    case 2:
        manualFillingAction();
        showAction(array->rows, array->columns, elements);
        deleteAction(array->rows, elements);
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    createAction();
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите почему выдает такую ошибку и как ее можно убрать. Код только в процессе написания, поэтому не обращайте внимание на пустые функции. А так программа выводит правильный результат.

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Детально не изучал, но бросается в глаза отсутствие `break` в конце каждого `case`. После выбора `case 1` сразу начинает выполнятся `case 2` (ведь нет `break`), и в нём происходит обращение к удалённому массиву.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: а в какой именно строке возникает ошибка известно?

Comment: void showAction(int row, int col, int* elements[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cout << elements[i][j] << "\t";//ошибка тут 
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

Comment: Ошибка возникла в этой функции

Comment: Там где cout << elements[i][j] << "\t";

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за оказанное внимание по решению этой проблемы. Я добавил ключевое слово break в конце каждого case, как и советовал пользователь wololo. Именно отсутствие этого ключевого слова привело к появлению этой ошибки.

Comment: Пишите не по тому адресу